# An static label for HTML Select

Tags: html, reactjs, select, label, dropdown

How we can fix the display label for Select (Not options), for example I've a select for **Radius** and I've multiple options like `50km`, `100km` and `500km`, I want user can choose any of this option, so whenever user selects any option, the dropdown menu closes and the selected value appears in Select element but I want display label for select should be always "Radius" not the selected value and the action should be similar as it working now.

```
<select
  onChange={e => valueSetterFunction(e.target.value)}
  value={value}
>
 {[
   { label: "50km", value 50 },
   { label: "100km", value 100 },
   { label: "500km", value 500 },
  ].map(ele =>
            <option
              key={ele.label}
              value={ele.value}
            >
              {ele.label}
            </option>)
}
</select>
```

Comment: what is `label` here ? it doesn't exist at all

Comment: I've updated the code snippet, but do have solution for above question?

Comment: I guess you want to have an empty string value with label of "Radius" ...

Comment: No, I want a String value for select, that should be static even we can select the option.

Comment: Please add expected output and how you want the select to behave when selected and all ... It's unclear

Comment: Just add a Static string instead of {ele.label} as "Radius" is that you want??